# Calculation when first condition has an impact on second

Tags: excel

Here is what I would like to solve.

A1: 200
B1: YES
C1: 10
D1: NO
E1: 20
F1: YES
G1: 30

I would like to make a calculation that would allow me to substract the number each time the condition is YES.

So in this example, it would be 200-10-30. However, as there are 8 conditions, I would need seven IF to do it. I was wondering if there was any other solution to do it.

So far I have a solution but that makes me create 3 news columns. I write IF(B1="YES,200-C1;200). And then I do the same on next 2 columns using each time the result from the previous column.

Thank you very much for your time

Comment: Can you change the YES and NO to + and -?  If so, do this: SUM(B1&A1,D1&C1...etc)

Comment: Thank you very much, I got it and hadn't thought about it. However this I would like to substract when it's "yes" (so "-" when it's yes) but I don't want any action when it's "no". How can I implement that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you might try

```
=A1-(SUMIF(B1:G1,"YES",C1))
```

setting C1 defines the first cell of the summed range and the formula can also be entered as

```
=A1-(SUMIF(B1:G1,"YES",C1:G1))
```

Comment: It works perfectly ! However I am kind of lost. Why is the last variable "C1" ? I am trying to understand even though the method works perfectly, thank you very much

Comment: I added what seems to be the explanation of the function behavior, although I didn't find documentation supporting it